# porting a CruiseControl build config to TeamCity

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, cruisecontrol.net

I have a bunch of MSBUILD files that we used with CrusieControl. 
I'm trying to use these with TeamCity. 
It looks like the MSBUILD proj files that we're using are expecting parameters from CruiseControl like *CCNetArtifactDirectory* and *CCNetWorkingDirectory* to name a couple.

I'm not sure how concepts like artifacts translate to team city.

Can I still have TeamCity pass in values for parameters that Cruise Control would have?

Does TeamCity pass in any variables that my MSBULD proj files can use? Like what is the current working directory? Can I ask TeamCity for its artifacts directory?

How do I setup an environment variable with TeamCity so that I can set a value for a variable called *CCNetArtifactDirectory* which my MSBUILD proj files can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go the Builder Parameters page of the build configuration in TeamCity, there is a section called System Properties.  These properties are passed in to MSBuild as properties.

So if you set up a System Property named "system.CCNetWorkingDirectory" and set it to the value "%teamcity.agent.work.dir%", then the CCNetWorkingDirectory parameter in MSBuild should be populated with the working directory of the agent.  TeamCity provides auto-complete for the available build parameters when you type "%" in the value field, so you should be able to use that and the TeamCity documentation to find what you need.

For artifacts, TeamCity has its own artifact caching system and you can specify the artifacts in the Artifact Paths section on the General Settings page.  I would recommend you start using that to cache your artifacts instead of having the MSBuild script move them, unless you want MSBuild to move them to a staging folder and then have TeamCity extract them from there.

Comment: cool, yeah. i have to do some cleaning up to truly port this stuff to team city, for sure. baby steps.

Comment: hey, so system variables and environment variables can be accessed in MSBUILD using the $ syntax? what's the difference between system and env variables and do the means by which they are accessed differ?

Comment: This is off the top of my head, but environment variables I believe are actually setting Windows environment variables, which can then be read by the MSBuild script or other apps triggered during the build process, so they have a wider scope.  System properties will be passed in directly to MSBuild as properties, presumably as part of the command line invocation, so it is more direct.  Where possible, I would say it is also better to use a system property.  I forget how to access environment variables from MSBuild, but the properties are just the standard $(CCNetWorkingDirectory) syntax.

Comment: what's the diff between system props and env vars? and are the config parameters used to toggle MSBUILD switches?